# Webpack doesn't recompile files after make changes (create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-router

I have a project that was created by create-react-app starter. After copying my project from one folder to another it has stopped recompiling files after making changes and saving. But if I make changes in root components it causes recompilation and I can see the changes on browser. I'm using react-router-redux, and I've realized that webpack does't recompile only components which nested in Route components. It's my routes :

```
<IndexRoute component={UserIsNotAuthenticated(HomePage)} />

<Route component={Auth}>
  <Route path="signup" component={SignupPage} />
  <Route path="login" component={LoginPage} />
  <Route path="forgot" component={ForgotPasswordPage} />
</Route>

<Route component={UserIsAuthenticated(Main)}>
  <Route component={ProfilePage} >
    <Route path="profile/edit" component={EditProfilePage} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="groups" component={GroupPage} />
  <Route path="about" component={AboutPage} />
  <Route path="contacts" component={ContactsPage} />
</Route>

<Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
```

So, if I make changes in components that're nested in "***Page" components source code doesn't recompile.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: there may be many reasons why webpack watcher is not working, what IDE are you using? what is your OS? did it work before you have moved project to another folder ?

Comment: Sublime Text 3, Ubuntu 16.04. Yes it worked until I've moved project.

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? I would initialize create-react-app in new folder, and copy project source after. It seems that paths in webpack are not updated...

Comment: No, I have not solved the problem yet( So, I just need to eject project and manually change the paths ?